# Can't perform logic operations on unsigned in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

I've a problem in performing logic operations on `unsigned`:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;    
with sel select
s_1<=a+b when "000",
a+((not b)+1) when "001",
s_2 when "010",
s_3 when "011",
s_4 when "100",
(others=>'0') when others;
```

Here there's an error:

> No feasible entries for prefix operator "not"

`s_1,a,b,s_2,s_3,s_4` are all of type `unsigned(31 downto 0)`.

I found a code that converts `std_logic_vector` to unsigned to enable logic operations on `std_logic_vector` if it can't be done on unsigned  but this code was using `numeric_std.all` which when used I think it conflicted with `std_logic_arith` and made the datatypes of unsigned unknown.

Now I don't know how to perform logic operations on unsigned and I don't know how to convert `std_logic_vector` to `unsigned`. Can someone help me?

Comment: Please add the library and use clauses to the question. If two definitions of "not" are visible, the compiler will hide them both rather than pick (possibly) the one you didn't intend. Best choice is ieee.std_logic_1164, ieee.numeric_std AND NOTHING ELSE! numeric_std certainly does define a "not" operator.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a non-standard library, `use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;`   which apparently does not implement the "not" operator.

`use ieee.numeric_std.all;`   in its place should resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A horrible workround would be to `xor` `b` with a vector of all ones...